# API for displaying permission of files

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

What API should be used to display the lists of permissions under the Security tab of a files or folders properties page?

Comment: Which OS you want to know?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: All depends on the file system.  Some have more permission attributes than others.

Comment: [`EditSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclui/nf-aclui-editsecurity)

Comment: Don't show security if the file system doesn't support it. It's oddly named, but the flag `FILE_PERSISTENT_ACLS` means a file-system supports security (i.e. ACLs plus owner, group, and control flags). You can query this via `GetVolumeInformation` or `GetVolumeInformationByHandle`. If a file system doesn't support security, files implicitly get an SD with Everyone (World) as the owner/group and a `NULL` DACL and SACL. AFAIK this is hard coded and can't be modified.

Comment: For example, this is the folder name/path:"C:\Intel" I have to print 1.full control 2.modify 3.read according to the permissions on this folder.